# Cofinal subsets are inadequate - example from Kelley, section 2 E

Tags: general-topology

My question is about neighborhood $U$ from following definition.

> Let $X$ be the set of all pairs of $\Bbb N_0$ with the topology described as follows:
> For each point $(m,n)$ other than $(0,0)$ the set $\{(m,n)\}$ is open.
> A set $U$ is a nbhd of $(0,0)$ *iff* for all except a finite number of integers $m$ the set $\{n:(m,n)\notin A\} =: B$ is finite.

Is finite number of integers taken out from $\Bbb N_0$ to form the set $B$ ?

> Visualizing $X$ in the Euclidean plane, a nbhd of $(0,0)$ contains all but a finite number of the members of all but a finite number of columns.

Is this a graph where whole plane is filled except $n\in \Bbb N$ columns are un-filled, and these columns are filled with $m \in \Bbb N$ points arbitrarily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ looks like this: there are finitely many columns that we don't care about, they can contain any points we like. But for all the other columns, we're only allowed to miss at most finitely many points per column. (We can have fully filled ones columns there, but we can also miss $(m,0)$ for all $m$ if we like, e.g.).

So you can have finitely many columns unfilled (or half fileld etc. ) and still miss infinitely many points in the remaining columns.

Comment: Seems different from nbhd defined for 'regular' topology: $U$ is a nbhd of $(0,0)$ *iff* $U$ contains an open set where $(0,0)$ belongs. Which is intuitively related to all members of nbhd.  But here it's just arbitrary set of points in arbitrary column in an Euclidian plane.

Comment: I wonder how would nbhd for $(m,m)$ where $m \in \Bbb N$ look like?

Comment: @flowian Its smallest neighbourhood is $\{(m,m)\}$.

Comment: @flowian The 'regular' topology is not defined; Kelley **defines**  the open sets of $\Bbb N_0 \times \Bbb N_0$ here, not of another topology (which would be the discrete one, as a subspace of the plane). He does this by specifying a base for the open neighbourhoods for each point. (there is a theorem in chapter 1 that allows you to define a topology like that, so the open sets now follow from this).

Comment: I don't follow what is the base specified for open neibhourhoods for each point?